# Cleaning Salesforce Production Environment

Tags: sandbox-refresh

Is there any way to delete and reset the data(Accounts,Organization,Profiles,Workflows,Rules etc) in Salesforce production environment.Currently I have planned to do it manually through DataLoader.Suggest me any other easy ways?

Comment: What do you mean by reset?

Comment: @Girbot Clearing all existing data including workflow,triggers,ApexClasses etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, but most of them use the [Ant Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm). I would recommend you check it out and if you have further questions, just open up a new one.

There are other tools, but most of them use the previous Ant one. One example is, for example, Copado. We use Copado at our office and it's extremely useful and easy to use, but the downside is that it's not free.

As a last resource, you can always do it by point and click... But against that si would recommend you learn how to use the first mentioned :)